# green and blue horizontal lines on google chrome youtube videos

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, video, youtube

I have these green and blue lines at the bottom of almost every youtube video that I play in google chrome. I had the similar problem in Manjaro so I don't think this problem is distro based. I am using a macbookpro with integrated intel graphics and already fixed the issue with screen tearing but this is google chrome problem I think.

I found that Brave Browser had similar issues in [this thread](https://community.brave.com/t/getting-colored-lines-in-youtube-videos-in-brave-and-not-on-google-chrome/143989)
that was related to fingerprinting but don't know how that would correlate to this.

Here is the image in my case
[image]

Anyone experienced this or know what could cause this or how to fix it?

I am using Google Chrome - **Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: Do you also have the problem in Firefox?

Comment: Try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1270843/274245

Comment: @vanadium no, I only get those in google-chrome. Although firefox is prone to screen tearing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem i solved by disabling the "Use Hardware Acceleration when available" in Settings/Advanced.
The problem is that the graphic card is not fully supported by Linux.

[image: Chrome Settings]

Comment: Disabling browser HA fixes all sorts of weird browser-related bugs and harms nothing. When in doubt, I recommend folks try that among their first steps in troubleshooting.

Comment: @Sergio It seems like this solved it right away but I tested it for a little while and it seems like you are right. I also turned off some response settings on my monitor which also reduced the number of lines and also lines were not present on all videos but disabling HA solved the problem completely.

Comment: The answer has just helped me to fix some weird renderings I've been seeing on arbitrary sites for the last week in Chrome on macOS 11.2.3