# Chrome full screen glitch

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

When I enter full screen in Chrome, the screen freezes. Say, for example, I open YouTube, plays a song and then when I click to full screen, the screen freezes, but the song is still goes on. I can hear the music is running but I see the screen like it is having some glitch.

After that, when I press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, it still shows a weird look.

I have attached Screenshots of both during full screen and after pressing the <kbd>Escape</kbd> button. Please help.

[image]

Comment: These are the images https://drive.google.com/file/d/11KIqUDM7Ho3oESsQD19D9RlFoS2OwIS4/view?usp=sharing,%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIAyszL4CoExJ2JTC6stHa1a6DppkRtu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by these sites.

[Problems with Chrome browser after suspending the computer on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[Chrome causing weird flickering since upgrade to 85.0.4183.83](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270689/chrome-causing-weird-flickering-since-upgrade-to-85-0-4183-83)

chrome://gpu/