# No ignore-gpu-blacklist at chrome://flags/ (Chrome causing weird flickering)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, google-chrome

I have similar to the post problem:

[Problems with Chrome browser after suspending the computer on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[image]

So I have  changed the `vulkan` based of [this post instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270689/chrome-causing-weird-flickering-since-upgrade-to-85-0-4183-83/1272506#1272506), as you can see below:

```
In my case, I go to chrome://flags/

Then enable:

#ignore-gpu-blacklist
#enable-vulkan
```

But I can not find the `ignore-gpu-blacklist` via my chrome setting as you can see below:

[image]

Some info about my OS:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

[image]

```
About Chrome
Chrome logo
Google Chrome
Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `ignore-gpu-blocklist` now.

[image]